# Heroku timing out when generating a Json needed for a view in a Ruby on Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asynchronous, heroku, pagination, sidekiq

My view requires a JSON that is being generated in the controller, the JSON is taking a good amount of time to generate when scaling for larger  information sets.  My problem is Heroku has a 30 second time limit for loading before it times out and for larger data sets it is timing out.

I have already implemented Redis to go and Sidekiq which has helped me with different features on the application.

The Show View is also paginated when there are larger data sets. No sure what my best option is here.

I am thinking of creating an intermediate page while creating the JSON asynchronously with Sidkiq and then alerting the user when the JSON is created and then allowing the user to go to the show view once loaded, which is a good option, but then I think I'll have an issue with the pagination which I am using the Kaminari Gem for.

Like I said I already use Sidekiq so I think this will be my best option.

```
def show
# @salesforce = true if @account.Name != nil 
@audit_report = audit_report
@measures_updated = MeasuresUpdated.new(audit_report: @audit_report)
@measures_updated = @measures_updated.check_measures_updated
@page_title = "Report based on \"#{@audit_report.name}\""
@context = ShowAuditReportContext.new(
  user: current_user,
  audit_report: @audit_report).audit_report_as_json
@context_measure_selections = @context[:audit_report][:measure_selections]
@context_measure_selections_array = @context[:audit_report][:measure_selections].to_a
@paginatable_array = Kaminari.paginate_array(@context_measure_selections_array).page(params[:page]).per(15)
```

end

this is in the controller  The @context is the issue, there are  a lot of calculcations in the backend placed in different classes that is taking a very long time to load.

I expect the user to visit the show page without timing out due server restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to think of this long JSON document as more like a report that the user is generating, rather than a view the user is requesting.

Paginating a JSON document will result in invalid JSON because opening and closing curly braces will (probably) not match up. So, perhaps it is more appropriate for the user to download the document. You could inform the user in the view of the location URL at which the document will be made available.

```
@filename = "Report#{@audit_report}.json"
CreateJsonReportJob.perform_async(@filename, @audit_report, current_user)
```

Then your Sidekiq job writes the file to that location

```
json = ShowAuditReportContext.new(
  user: current_user,
  audit_report: audit_report
).audit_report_as_json

File.open(filename, "w+") do |f|
  f.write(json)
end
```

To get fancier, you could create a table of reports that the user can view and manage. You could use Active Storage to manage the attachments.

Comment: NB: since they are on Heroku, you can't depend on local filenames, need to use S3 or similar.

Comment: sorry should have mentioned the view will be editable also with different fields that then use ajax to update the view and models